# how to pass arguments to a ref parameters using c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, arguments

In this code, I want to pass some value to a method inside a **thread**. How can i do this? please help me..

```
private void onMessageReceivedThreading(ref SMSDeliver myMessage)
{
    onreceiveThread = new Thread(()=> onMessageReceived(myMessage));
    onreceiveThread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may think about assigning it to a local variable, like:

```
private void onMessageReceivedThreading(ref SMSDeliver myMessage)
{
      var mess = myMessage; 
      onreceiveThread = new Thread(()=> onMessageReceived(mess ));
      onreceiveThread.Start();
}
```

Worth to mention (it's not a clear from the post) if

- `myMessage` is a reference type, you still reference *to the same instance of type*, so may meet some concurency problems. Pay attention on this.
- `myMessage` is a value type, no concurency problem may happen here (as you copy, create a new instance of a structure), but you need to pay attention on fact that if `onMessageReceived` affects state of `mess` in some way, merge changes to original `myMessage` instance, *after* thread execution completed.